# PyQt / PySide displaying child dialogue with Qt.FramelessWindowHint

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyside

Essentially i'm trying to set up a UiDialogue which is created and shown when a button in its parent Ui is pressed.

I want the parent Dialogue to be frameless (which is working and displaying as expected) however the child dialogue will only show if it is made with a frame.

If the commented out line on line 24 is uncommented, the window fails to show but the app does not signal any kind of error. Can anybody tell me why?
Below is a stripped down version of the code, any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

```
import sys
from    PySide.QtCore  import  *
from    PySide.QtGui   import  *

class Ui_box(object):
    def setupUi(self, box):
        box.setObjectName("box")
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint);
        box.resize(749, 344)
        self.p_b = QPushButton(box)
        self.p_b.setGeometry(QRect(241, 140, 141, 91))
        self.p_b.show()

        self.retranslateUi(box)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(box)

    def retranslateUi(self, box):
        box.setWindowTitle(QApplication.translate("WelcomeUI", "Tasker", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


class Ui_Innerbox(object):
    def setupUi(self, Innerbox):
        Innerbox.setObjectName("Innerbox")
        #self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint);
        Innerbox.resize(745, 340)
        self.label = QLabel(Innerbox)
        self.label.setText("this is me")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(239, 140, 141, 91))
        self.label.show()


        self.retranslateUi(Innerbox)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Innerbox)

    def retranslateUi(self, Innerbox):
        Innerbox.setWindowTitle(QApplication.translate("WelcomeUI", "Tasker", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))



class InnerBox(QDialog, Ui_Innerbox):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)




class Box(QDialog, Ui_box):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        self.p_b.clicked.connect(self.pressed_button)

    def pressed_button(self):

        self.Innerb = InnerBox(self)
        self.hide()
        self.Innerb.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv);

    newb = Box()
    print("made")
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ive found that the desired behaviour can be achieved if the 'child' controller is not given its parent as a initialisation argument and setting child.setModal('true')

The child will by default set its position match that of its modal predecessor.